# Load all audit files with sys.dm_server_audit_status and sys.fn_get_audit_file method?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to load all audit logs listed in `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_audit_status`, then execute `sys.fn_get_audit_file` method for all files found in the query.

Is that possible? Maybe something similar to `sp_MSforeachtable`?

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer right now but can you feed the results from the audit status DMV to the get results function with a `cross apply`?

Answer (score 0):

The defintion for `sys.fn_get_audit_file` identifies that the "file_pattern" parameter can include wildcards.

If you have all your Audits going to a common folder and then split by audit below that then you could include enough of the path to include them all.

Otherwise simply query them all and `UNION` the results.

Comment: With wildcard, I will have to input a fixed path. I need something that works on any file locations

Comment: Use the value from your query and build a Dynamic SQL query which allows you to adjust and add wildcards

Comment: That's what the dynamic SQL will allow - build the query string and then execute it. It will not need additional input once you have defined the steps

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: This assumes you have a single Audit file. Adjust it to many by e.g. using a CURSOR to move through each value returned from sys.dm_server_audit_status

`DECLARE @quey NVARCHAR(max); 
 DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(max);
 SELECT @path = audit_file_path FROM sys.dm_server_audit_status;
 SELECT @path = SUBSTRING(@path, 1, <find the length to the final folder spilt in the name using e.g. REVERSE & CHARINDEX>);
 SELECT @query = N'SELECT * FROM sys.fn_get_audit_file (' + @path + N'\*, NULL, NULL)';
EXEC sp_executesql @query;`